# comboBox how to deactive to write in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have combo box with datasource. I want to use only can choose items not write in it.
How can I make that?

Comment: @Oded: looks like it's not WPF: on WPF default value of `Combobox.IsEditable` is `false`.

Comment: @Vlad - I will not assume defaults or built in controls... could easily be third party, custom made or with changed defaults.

Comment: @Oded: you are right, let's wait for the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList`